# Submit button not working! MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

```
@model CommonLayer.ORDER
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Update";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h4>Update Order Status</h4>
<br />

@if (Model.OrderStatus != "Shipped")
{
using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderId, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "font-size:medium", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "font-size:medium", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="form-control" name="OrderStatus">
                    <option value="Pending" id="pending">Pending</option>
                    <option value="Shipped" id="shipped">Shipped</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderDate, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "font-size:medium", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "font-size:medium", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <form action="/order/update/@Model.OrderId" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
}
}
else
{
<h4>Order Has Been Shipped!</h4>
}
```

My submit button isn't working regardless of the correct syntax being used. When I press the button nothing happens, as if I haven't clicked it, no redirecting whatsoever.

Was working until yesterday. Did not change any code whatsoever regarding the form or corresponding controller.

This is the controller corresponding to the form.

```
[HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "ADM")]
    public ActionResult Update(Guid Id)
    {
        BusinessLayer.Orders order = new BusinessLayer.Orders();
        return View(order.GetOrder(Id));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "ADM")]
    public ActionResult Update(CommonLayer.ORDER order, Guid id)
    {
        BusinessLayer.Orders blorder = new BusinessLayer.Orders();
        blorder.UpdateOrder(order);
        return RedirectToAction("UpdateDetails", new {id=id});
    }
```

Comment: Use [`@Html.BeginForm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.FormExtensions.BeginForm%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod%29) and move `@Model.OrderId` into an `<input type="hidden">`.

Comment: I'm already using the @ with the if, so an error will be shown when I try to use it with using aswell

Comment: I meant, use that instead of your manual `<form>` tag. I did not notice you also had a `BeginForm` on top, which makes it a nested form, which is not a valid html. Just remove the `<form>` then and put the route parameters into the `BeginForm`.

Comment: Still did not work :( this was working until yesterday, I dont know what could have happened as I havent changed anything within the form or the corresponding controllers

Comment: Not relavent to this question per se but for me, my button was not inside the `using (Html.BeginForm) {}` Remember it needs to be inside. Moving it inside worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code, let us know if doesn't work

Added below line to pass the orderid

> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderId)

Updated below line to call action of a controller

> Html.BeginForm("update","order",FormMethod.Post)

Finally removed the unnecessary form tag

Removed antiforgerytoken from view as you are not checking in you action method.
If you want to add that then you need to add [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  after [httppost] of Update Action method

```
@model CommonLayer.ORDER
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Update";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h4>Update Order Status</h4>
    <br />

    @if (Model.OrderStatus != "Shipped")
    {
    using (Html.BeginForm("Update","Order",FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderId)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderId, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "font-size:medium", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "font-size:medium", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <select class="form-control" name="OrderStatus">
                        <option value="Pending" id="pending">Pending</option>
                        <option value="Shipped" id="shipped">Shipped</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderDate, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "font-size:medium", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @style = "font-size:medium", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    }
    }
    else
    {
    <h4>Order Has Been Shipped!</h4>
    }
```

Comment: You could at least briefly summarize what changes were made comparing to the original code.

Comment: copied your code, still didn't work :( this was working yesterday with the that same code I've posted and all of a sudden the submit button doesn't do anything

Comment: I'll try that janina. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, janina I tried commenting bit by bit and it seems that when I exclude the OrderDate part, it works. Any clue on why is this ?

Comment: nothing I simply try to press the update button and nothing happens, no redirection or error whatsoever. I would greatly appreciate your help mate

Comment: Sure, what is the data type of OrderDate, did u try to input some valid value in orderdate text field and then submit?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong on your OrderDate part, may be you are getting validation error

Comment: the data type is DateTime, and I'm not allowed to change the value of orderdate hence the readonly.

Comment: I'll just mark it as hidden, as long as it works. Thanks alot for your help buddy